# Adding additional attribute to @State property

Tags: swiftui, property-wrapper

I have a SwiftUI view that takes user name in a String declared as a State property.
How can I add an additional attribute to the same variable?

```swift
struct Login: View {
    @Trimmed(characterSet: .whitespaces)
    @State private var userName: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextEditor(text: $userName)
        }
    }        
}
```

In the code above, I am trying to add a property wrapper `Trimmed` that will automatically keep the user input string clean.

I am getting an error saying `Cannot convert value of type 'State<String>' to expected argument type 'String'`

Is there a way out here?

---

Update:

Here is the code for the property wrapper

```swift
@propertyWrapper
struct Trimmed {
    private var value: String!
    private let characterSet: CharacterSet

   var wrappedValue: String {
        get { value }
        set { value = newValue.trimmingCharacters(in: characterSet) }
    }

   init(wrappedValue: String) {
        self.characterSet = .whitespacesAndNewlines
        self.wrappedValue = wrappedValue
    }

   init(wrappedValue: String, characterSet: CharacterSet) {
        self.characterSet = characterSet
        self.wrappedValue = wrappedValue
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you put @State first?

Comment: Can you give me some information about the `@Trimmed` property?

Comment: Putting the @State first fixes it. Thanks. I am getting an error on Binding TextEditor(text: $userName). It says it cannot convert value of type Binding<Trimmed> to Binding<State>. I have updated the code for Trimmed property wrapper

Comment: Why not just extend String?

Comment: @loremipsum. extending string will work, but again that has to be explicitly invoked. I am looking for a declarative option

Answer (score 1):

See [the Swift Evolution Proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0258-property-wrappers.md#composition-of-property-wrappers) for how property wrapper composition works. By writing `@Trimmed` first, you are actually doing:

```
private var _userName = Trimmed(
    // that's not what Trimmed.init takes!
    wrappedValue: State(wrappedValue: "")
    characterSet: .whitespaces
)

var userName: String {
    get { _userName.wrappedValue.wrappedValue }
    set { _userName.wrappedValue.wrappedValue = newValue }
}
```

If you put `State` first,

```
@State @Trimmed(characterSet: .whitespaces) var userName = ""
```

then you get:

```
private var _userName = State(
    wrappedValue: Trimmed(wrappedValue: "", characterSet: .whitespaces)
)
```

Which is correct as far as types are concerned.

However, such a `userName` has a `projectedValue` of `Binding<Trimmed>`, which is probably not what you want. You can't use this in a `TextField` for example.

```
// wrong type
TextField("Foo", text: $text)

// this also doesn't work because setting the Binding is nonmutating, 
// and so doesn't call your wrappedValue's setter
TextField("Foo", text: $text.value)
```

So you actually *have* to put `Trimmed` first, so that `Trimmed` can take a `State` and have its own `projectedValue` of type `Binding<String>`. But that still won't work. You can't detect when the `State` changes and remove the whitespaces, because `State` has a `nonmutating` setter.

I think you'd have to dig into the implementation details of SwiftUI to make something like this work.

I would suggest just using the `onChange` view modifier instead. That is the "correct way" to detect a change in `@State`.

```
// modify the outermost view with this, and the same would apply to the children
.onChange(of: userName) { newValue in
    userName = newValue.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
}
```

Extract this as a view modifier if you like.

```
struct Trimmed: ViewModifier {
    @Binding var text: String
    let characterSet: CharacterSet
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.onChange(of: text) { newValue in
            text = newValue.trimmingCharacters(in: characterSet)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `@State` inside your `Trimmed` propertyWrapper it would work without chaining it with `@State` in your view:

```
@propertyWrapper
struct Trimmed: DynamicProperty {
    @State private var value: String
    private let characterSet: CharacterSet
    
    var wrappedValue: String {
        get {
            value
        }
        nonmutating set {
            value = newValue.trimmingCharacters(in: characterSet)
            
        }
    }
    var projectedValue: Binding<String> {
        Binding {
            return wrappedValue
        } set: { newValue in
            wrappedValue = newValue
        }
    }
    init(wrappedValue: String, characterSet: CharacterSet = .whitespacesAndNewlines) { //merged 2 initializers into 1
        self.characterSet = characterSet
        self._value = State(wrappedValue: wrappedValue.trimmingCharacters(in: characterSet))
    }
}
```

Then simply use `@Trimmed`:

```
struct Login: View {
    @Trimmed(characterSet: .whitespaces) private var userName: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextEditor(text: $userName)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Only some parts of my app are in SwiftUI. Your solution will not work for UIKit. Also at the call site, having a State declaration would be more important than having a secondary property wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved the above problem

```
struct Login: View {
  
    @State @Trimmed private var userName: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextEditor(text: Binding(get: {userName}, set: { userName = $0 }))
        }
    }        
}
```

As suggested by Fogmeister in the comments, I moved `@Trimmed` after the `@State`. With this, the SwiftUI views respond to the changes in userName

Regarding the text binding. I wrote a small Binding inline.

This solution is completely declarative, concise and reusable. Also, the trimming happens implicitly.